# How to use the batch file for displaying the file name after copied

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I have a batch file which will copy all the files from one location to another location.

But i want to display the file name which was copying to another location when i run the batch file.

Example:

```
copy /-y "%File%\Sample.exe"    "%DestinationDrive%"
```

I have the command like above in my batch file, but when i run the batch file i was getting the output in cmd window as "1 file(s) copied."

Instead of that i need the output like "Sample.exe copied."

How can I do this?

Comment: but you copy 1 file, so you know what it is that you are copying. Are you specifying each file you want to copy in the script?

Comment: Yes i was specifying each and every file name, but after running the script i was getting it as 1 file(s)copied,

Comment: So do you only want to copy certain files, or all files in a directory?

Comment: But specifically i need the file name which it was copied to the destination folder

Comment: Yes, but are you copying ALL files in directory or only specific files?

Comment: Specific files only i was copying

Comment: so then put the files you want to copy in a file and read from it, then echo the variables.

Comment: I can echo the variable but instead of that after copying, instead of showing it as 1 file(s) copied, do we have any better option for directly showing like Sample.txt copied.

Comment: see answer for a better way

Comment: Pleae read answer again. Thorouhly

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 simple methods to achieve this.

The **better** method is to avoid the temp file and add all the files you want to copy, to a variable in the script, in this case called `myfiles`.

We just iterate through the variable entries and process each one. This example also pipes the `copy` process to `nul` which will only allow you to see the echo of each filename, instead of the actual copy process.

```
@echo off
set myfiles="example.exe","example2.dll","example3.txt","example4.inf"
for %%i in (%myfiles%) do (
  copy /-y "%file%\%%~i" "%DestinationDrive%" >nul && echo Copied %%~i
)
```

So my example result is:

```
D:\>simulate.cmd
Copied example1.exe
Copied example2.dll
Copied example3.txt
Copied example4.inf
```

---

The **Temp file** method:

Create a file with the files you want to copy:

**Filename.txt**

```
file.txt
this_file.exe
example.dll
somefile.txt
```

then create a batch file:

**batchfile.cmd**

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (filename.txt) do (
  copy /-y "%File%\%%i" "%DestinationDrive%" > nul && echo Copied %%i
)
```

**PS!!** I used you `/-y` as per your example, if you want to actually over write files without prompting for confirmation, rather use `/y`

Comment: This was ok for the single file, if we have multiple files that need to be copied then, what was the condition.

Comment: you may want the `Copied ...` only, when the `copy` was successful: `copy /-y "%File%\%%i" "%DestinationDrive%" >nul && echo Copied %%i`

Comment: @Stephan Yeah, that seems like a plan. Updated!

Comment: Nice tip!  I did not know that you could store a delimited *list* in a batch file variable.  This was exactly what I needed.